# Web3 js APIs Installation Requirements

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, nodejs

If I am using Infura Node interact with smart contracts. And I want to build/setup web3 apis on a ubuntu machine on AWS. Do i need to install truffle on that machine or just node.js and web3 is enough?

Comment: node.js and web3 is enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Download Node.js and npm from https://nodejs.org/en/, and then install them.
2. Run `npm install web3`.

Answer (score 0):

Does this mean we just need to move the build folder at web3 server? and we don’t need truffle compile or truffle setup there?